# how to delete all contacts from android mobile by name

Tags: android

How to delete all contacts number by name from android device.
if number is stored in SDCard and what ever location, how to delete using programmatly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
    String your_contact_name = "John Doe";

    Cursor pCur = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME +" = ?", new String[]{your_contact_name}, null);
    while (pCur.moveToNext())
    {
        String lookupKey = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
        context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
    }
```